Quadratic form of a real symmetric matrix is bounded
If $\lambda_1>\lambda_2>...>\lambda_r$ are the different eiegenvues of a real symmetric matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$.
$1.$
Show that the quadratic form associated to $A$ satisfies for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ the inequalities:
$$ \lambda_r||x||^2\leq q(x)\leq \lambda_1||x||^2$$
$2.$ Verify that the maximum and minimum values of $q(x)$ over the unitary sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are $\lambda_1$ $\lambda_r$, respectively.


Clearly, $q$ is given by $q(x)=x^TAx$, where $x=(x_1,...,x_n)^T$. Now, given that $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, then $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable. So, let $\{v_1,...,v_r\}$ orthogonal vectors associated to $\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_r\}$, respectively.

Now, let $P$ be the matrix whose $i$-th column is $v_i$, and $D$ the matrix whose $i$-th diagonal entry is $\lambda_i$. This way, we have $$A=PDP^T,$$
and $P^TP=I.$
Taking $v=P^Tx$ gives $$v^Tv=x^T(PP^T)x=x^Tx.$$
Then, we have $$x^TAx=x^T(PDP^T)x=v^TDv=\sum_{i=1}^{r} \lambda_iv_i^2.$$
Since the eigenvalues are listed in decreasing order, we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{r}\lambda_rv_i^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{r}\lambda_iv_i^2 \leq\sum_{i=1}^{r}\lambda_1v_i^2.$$
However, I don't feel like I can conclude the desired result from what I have done so far. I feel like I'm missing something.
Any help for part $1.$ and part $2.$? Or perhaps any reference where this statement is proved? (I found a book which mentioned this result, but offered no proof of it).

On related note, this result has neat geometry. Contours of positive quadratic forms are ellipses, with axes given by eigenvectors and length by reciprocal of eigenvalues (try to see why). The ellipse gets larger for larger values. To maximise (minimise) while satisfying the constraint, you can imagine the ellipse circumscribed (inscribed) on the unit sphere. At this point the minor (major) axis of the ellipse is kissing the unit sphere. The length of this axis is of course, given by $1/\lambda_1$ ($1/\lambda_n$), which is why the extrema are associated with greatest and smallest eigenvalues.

Well, first, there is a problem in your notation, since you seem to assume that $r=n$.
Let us start from the beginning. Let $P$ be the matrix whose columns are an orthormal (for the standard inner product) basis $\mathcal{B}=(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$ (this basis exists by the Spectral Theorem).
Since $\mathcal{B}$ is orthonormal, we have $P^TP=I_n$.
Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of eigenvectors,  $D=P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal, and its entries $d_1,\ldots,d_n$ are precisely the eigenvalues of $A$ (with some repetitions eventually).
By definition, $\lambda_r\leq d_i\leq \lambda_1$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$.
You can always order your basis in such a way that the first diagonal entry of $D$ is $\lambda_r$, and the last one is $\lambda_1$, with your notation, if you want to.
Since $P^T=P^{-1}$, we have $D=P^TAP$.
But $P^TAP$ is the matrix of the quadratic form $q$ wrt $\mathcal{B}$.
Using the definition of this matrix, this means that $q(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i e_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n d_i v_i^2$.
Moreover, since $\mathcal{B}$ is an orthonormal wrt to the standard inner product, we have $\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n v_i e_i\Vert^2=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2$.
To sum up, if $x=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i e_i$, we have:

$\Vert x\Vert^2 =\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2$

$q(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n d_i v_i^2$.


Since $\lambda_r\leq d_i\leq \lambda_1$, you get
$\lambda_r(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n d_i v_i^2\leq \lambda_1(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2)$ for all $v_1,\ldots,v_n$.
But, using the two previous equalities, you get 1.
There is no difficulty to get 2. from 1., since the unit sphere is the set of vectors $x$ such that $\Vert x\Vert=1$. If you have 1. , you have $\lambda_1\leq q(x)\leq \lambda_r$ for all $x$ on the unit sphere.
You just have to check that the bounds can be attained. But it is enough to evaluate $q$ at some eigenvector $e_i\in\mathcal{B}$ corresponding to $\lambda_r$ and $\lambda_1$ respectively.


Adding to @GreginGre's answer with more steps. Since A is real and symmetric, we can write, $A = V \Lambda V^T$ where $\lambda = \text{diag}[\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_r], \lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \lambda_r$ and V is a unitary matrix $\in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$, such that, $V^{-1} = V^T$.

Now, we have
\begin{align*}
q(x) = x^T A x &= x^T V \Lambda V^T x \\
&= (V^T x)^T \Lambda (V^T x) \\
&\text{Using $u = V^T x = \sum_{i=1}^r v_i^T x$ with $u = [u_1 \cdots u_r]^T$}, \\
q(x) &= u^T \Lambda u = \sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i u_i^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i (v_i^T x)^2
\end{align*}
Now, using the inequalities $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \lambda_r$, we can write:
\begin{align*}
& \lambda_1 \sum_{i=1} (v_i^T x)^2 \geq \sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i (v_i^T x)^2 \geq \lambda_n \sum_{i=1} (v_i^T x)^2 \\
&\implies \lambda_1 \sum_{i=1}^r v_i^2 \geq q(x) \geq \lambda_r \sum_{i=1}^r v_i^2 \\
&\implies \lambda_1 ||u||^2 \geq q(x) \geq \lambda_r ||u||^2
\end{align*}
Now, $||u||^2 = u^T u = (V^T x)^T (V^T x) = x^T V V^T x = x^T x = ||x||^2$. Therefore,
$$\lambda_1 ||x||^2 \geq q(x) \geq \lambda_r ||x||^2 - \text{Q.E.D.}$$

For the second part of the question, we need to find max, min $q(x)$ such that $||x||^2 = 1$. Now, this is easy if we plug-in $||x||^2 = 1$ in the previous inequality we have proved. However, if we want to understand why, we have the optimisation problem:

\begin{align*}
& \max q(x) \ s.t. \ ||x||^2 = 1 \\
& \max x^T A x \ s.t. \ ||x||^2 = 1 \\
& \max (V^T x)^ T \Lambda (V^T x) \ s.t. \ ||x||^2 = 1
\end{align*}
Let's try $x = v_1$, i.e, the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of A. This satisfies $||x||^2 = ||v_1||^2 = 1$.
\begin{align*}
\max q(x) &= \max (V^T v_1)^T \Lambda (V^T v_1) \\
&= \max e_1^T \Lambda e_1 \ \text{where $e_1 = [1, 0 ,\cdots, 0]^T$} \\
&= \lambda_1
\end{align*}
The eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue is also the principal component of $A$. Similarly, we can choose $x = v_r$ to get $\min q(x) \ s.t. ||x||^2=1$.
